# mod_rewrite vs mod_rewrite.c, Is there a difference?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is wordpress `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Is `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c></IfModule>` to check whether `mod_rewrite` module has been loaded on server? Also if `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c></IfModule>` is for `mod_rewrite` then why does `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c></IfModule>` uses `mod_rewrite` instead of `mod_rewrite.c`? Is it referring to source file as mentioned [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

[image]

Comment: `mod_rewrite.c` instead of `mod_rewrite.c` ???

Comment: Sorry it was `mod_rewrite`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#ifmodule

Syntax:

```
<IfModule [!]module-file|module-identifier> ... </IfModule>
```

And it's `mod_rewrite.c` or `rewrite_module` for Apache Module mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#ifmodule

> The `<IfModule test>...</IfModule>` section is used to mark directives
>   that are conditional on the presence of a specific module. The
>   directives within an  section are only processed if the test
>   is true. If test is false, everything between the start and end
>   markers is ignored.
>
> The module argument can be either the module identifier or the file
>   name of the module, at the time it was compiled. For example,
>   rewrite_module is the identifier and mod_rewrite.c is the file name.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/module-dict.html#SourceFile

> Source File
>
> This quite simply lists the name of the source file which contains the
>   code for the module. This is also the name used by the `<IfModule>`
>   directive.

In laymans yes the IfModule condition checks if a module is loaded. Yes mod_rewrite.c is the Source file.